# How do I configure my DNS properly

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I've just purchased a new domain name, and have set up hosting space, but the domain registrars wont allow me to change the dns servers until the server passes dns tests, but on zonecheck.fr I get a message :

```
---- fatal ----
f: The nameserver list doesn't match the given one

The given nameserver list (ns1.mydomain.com, ns2.mydomain.com) is not consistent with the one retrieved from the zone (ns1.mydomain.com).

ns2.mydomain.com/123.123.123.123
```

The dns records I have set up for the new domain are :

```
$ttl 38400
@   IN  SOA ns1.mydomain.com. hostmaster.mydomain.com. (
        2011071906
        10801
        3600
        604800
        38400 )
otherdomain.com.    IN  A   123.123.123.123
www.otherdomain.com.    IN  A   123.123.123.123
ftp.otherdomain.com.    IN  A   123.123.123.123
m.otherdomain.com.  IN  A   123.123.123.123
localhost.otherdomain.com.  IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.otherdomain.com.    IN  A   123.123.123.123
admin.otherdomain.com.  IN  A   123.123.123.123
mail.otherdomain.com.   IN  A   123.123.123.123
otherdomain.com.    IN  MX  5 mail.otherdomain.com.
otherdomain.com.    IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:otherdomain.com ip4:123.123.123.123 ?all"
```

The new domain name uses my main dns servers from my other domain name which has private nameservers. The configuration is :

```
$ttl 38400
@   IN  SOA server1.mydomain.com. root.server1.mydomain.com. (
        1303077376
        10800
        3600
        604800
        38400 )
mydomain.com.   IN  A   123.123.123.123
www.mydomain.com.   IN  A   123.123.123.123
ftp.mydomain.com.   IN  A   123.123.123.123
m.mydomain.com. IN  A   123.123.123.123
server1.mydomain.com.   IN  A   123.123.123.123
localhost.mydomain.com. IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.mydomain.com.   IN  A   123.123.123.123
admin.mydomain.com. IN  A   123.123.123.123
mail.mydomain.com.  IN  A   123.123.123.123
mydomain.com.   IN  MX  5 mail.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:mydomain.com ip4:123.123.123.123 ?all"
mydomain.com.   IN  NS  ns1.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.   IN  NS  ns2.mydomain.com.
ns1.mydomain.com.   IN  A   123.123.123.123
ns2.mydomain.com.   IN  A   234.234.234.234
paypal.mydomain.com.    IN  A   123.123.123.123
www.paypal.mydomain.com.    IN  A   123.123.123.123
ftp.paypal.mydomain.com.    IN  A   123.123.123.123
m.paypal.mydomain.com.  IN  A   123.123.123.123
localhost.paypal.mydomain.com.  IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.paypal.mydomain.com.    IN  A   123.123.123.123
admin.paypal.mydomain.com.  IN  A   123.123.123.123
mail.paypal.mydomain.com.   IN  A   123.123.123.123
paypal.mydomain.com.    IN  MX  5 mail.paypal.mydomain.com.
```

What do I need to do to get otherdomain.com validated on zonecheck.fr?

Comment: it's much easier for others to help you - and to diagnose the issues - if you don't obscure your domain. you'll be publishing your dns publicly to the world, so there's really no security advantage to obscuring the actual dns.

Comment: Have you acquired a copy of DNS and BIND ( http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100575 ) yet?  If not this should be your first acquisition and read prior to trying to do **ANYTHING** involving DNS on the internet.  This book is easily worth several times its purchase price.

Comment: Please add your domain, it's hard to tell you were you went wrong if we can't check ourselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the first step would be to add `NS` records to `otherdomain.com`'s zone.  Second, fix up your zone file formatting to be columnised; reading in a zigzag is painful.

Comment: +1 on both counts: Add the NS records, and if it's still broken please update the question with columnized zone files.  My brain melted trying to follow the current text above :-(